# Problem with Route Attribute in microservice api gateway

Tags: c#, rest, microservices, api-gateway

I am writing a Microservice API gateway and I want to route the client request to the appropriate Microservice. When Microservice comes up they introduce their services to API gateway and we store them in Redis.

```
{
  "Id": "api/values.put",
  "Microservice": "Sample",
  "Controller": "api/Values",
  "Action": "",
  "Method": "Put",
  "IpAddress": "http://localhost:4560"
}
```

For example client calls /service/Company from the gateway and I find the  Microservice that can handle this request and route the request to that.

But I have problems in some situations.

I have a controller like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Company")]
public class CompanyController : ApiControllerRead
{
    public IEnumerable<Company> Get()
    {
        return new List<Company>();
    }

    public Company Get(int id)
    {
        return new Company();
    }

    [Route("{companyId}/Employees")]
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees(int companyId)
    {
        // Filter Data
        return new List<Employee>();
    }

    [Route("{companyId}/Employees/{employeeId}")]
    public Employee GetEmployeeById(int companyId, int employeeId)
    {
        // Filter Data
        return new Employee();
    }
}
```

Default if client request `/service/Company` I can easily find the Microservice from Redis and send request.

But the problem arise when we need to use Route attribute.

We think to store Route Attributes in database like this:

```
{
   "Id": "api/company.getemployeebyid",
   "Microservice": "Sample",
   "Controller": "api/Company",
   "Action": "",
   "Method": "GetEmployeeById",
   "IpAddress": "http://localhost:4560",
   "Route" : "{companyId}/Employees/{employeeId}"
}
```

So, if client calls `/service/Company/1/Employees/1`, how can I determine that this URL matches to `{companyId}/Employees/{employeeId}` Route?

Comment: Not sure if it helps you, but you could try to not store routes in database, but generate such information automatically on startup of your app. You can use swagger.json to describe your api endpoints ([link1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-2.1), [link2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Cvisual-studio-xml)). When microservice introduce itself, it points to swagger.json, your apigateway will parse it and use later for routing.

Comment: If you are using routes copied and pasted from your code, you could use components from the routing infrastructure of the matching version of ASP.NET to try to parse the incoming request path and figure out which (if any) routes are matched. For example, I think ASP.NET Core has a TemplateParser and TemplateMatcher?

Comment: The answer is simple that you need to enumerate through the db context and find a match.  It is not clear from you question if you are having an issue doing the enumeration or matching the results with the classes.

Comment: The easiest way i can think of is that while looping through all the route lists you can search something like `currentRoute.Route.IndexOf("{")` and if you find one replace it with the first parameter. Even easier you can change the named `{companyId}` with `{0}` (as it doesnt matter to your getaway) and then use `string.Format(currentRoute.Route,companyId,employeeId)`